# Kendo-ui Grid: "date" type columns

Tags: json, date, kendo-ui, grid

I am using kendo-ui grid.

The dataSource comes from a json file, and the column's headers also come from a json file.

Problem is that several of the column's data is a date in a Json format (for example: 1238943952000).

How can I tell the grid that it's a date?

The only solution that worked for me was:

```
        columns: [
            {
                field: "myfield",
                title: "myfield!!",                  
                template: Date(myfield),
            }...
        ]
```

But I want to take the headers from a json file and not like that, and also I want to be able to format it.

---

I tried using the "template" option:

template: '<#= kendo.toString(myfield, " MMM. dd, yyyy") #>'

template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(myfield, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #"

---

Also the format option:

format:"{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"

---

Also the "parse" and "model" inside the "schema":

```
            schema  : {
                data: "myData",
                type: 'json',
                parse : function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, val){
                        val = toDate(val);
                    });
                    return data;
                }
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        myfield: { type: "date" }
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

But nothing worked.

How can I do it and still use the Json files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the below changes to model and columns -

```
 model: {
   fields: {
     myfield: { type: "date", parse: function(value) { return new Date(value); }},
   }
 },

 columns: { 
   field: 'myfield',
   template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(myfield, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #"
 },
```

Comment: Please edit your code part with proper indentations.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following, parsing on model level can be skipped by creating date object in template directly

```
columns: { 
field: 'myfield',
template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(new Date(myfield), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #"
}
```